# Blow up and Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, blowup

Let $\pi : Z = \widetilde{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}$ be the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ along an irreducible non-degenerate  smooth curve $\mathcal{C}$ of degree $d$. According to the question ([Direct Image by a Blow up](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418481)) and answer we have $$\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}(-nE) = I_{\mathcal{C}/ \mathbb{P}^{3}}^{n}$$

In the following papper : **On The Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity Of Product Of Ideal sheaves**, Jessica Sidman (arXiv:math/0110184) we have

> **Proposition 1.7** : Suppose that $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are ideal sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ with regularities $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$, respectively. Suppose also that zeros of $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ intersect in a set of dimension at most one.  Then $\mathcal{I} \cdot \mathcal{J}$ is $(m_{1} + m_{2})$-regular.

Now, according to proposition 1.8.46 of **Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I**, we have $\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}}$ is $(d - 1)$-regular.

Suppose that proposition 1.7 applies to a finite number of ideal sheaves.

Making $\mathcal{I} = \mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}} = \mathcal{J}$ in the **proposition 1.7** we can conclude that $$\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}}^{n} = \underbrace{\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}} \cdot \mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}} \cdots \cdot \mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}}}_{n-\text{times}}$$ is $$n \bigl(d - 1 \bigr)-\text{regular}?$$

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question here? The results you quote in your post (assuming they are correct) appear to prove the claim you're interested in, unless I've missed something. Do you have reason to believe that some part of this is incorrect, or are you looking for confirmation that putting all of this together works like you think it should (or something else)?

Comment: Dear KReiser.  I would just like to know if the above is correct.

Comment: @KReiser. Just a question here. In this case, what would be the set of zeros of $\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}}^{n}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: My first reaction is that you must be kidding - if you can't figure out the answer to the question "where does $I_C^n$ vanish" on your own, you should take some time to sort out the basics of the subject. If you can't answer that question on your own, then dealing with things like the question in your post s like trying to run before you can crawl.

Comment: Well, first of all, I don't play here on this forum. I know that each sheaf of ideal cancels out over the curve. I'm simply asking if this remains true for the product $\mathcal{I}_{\mathcal{C}}^{n}$. I know I have a lot to learn in this important area of Mathematics (Algebraic Geometry). If my question was too trivial and it offended your intellectual property, I apologize.